# Matching data in sql and display it through php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do matchmaking website.
Currently I have two tables which are user profile and their partner profile(which is the requirement that those users hope for). I have to match this two table by using mysql and php. maybe fuzzy logic?
For example, user A hopes for tall partner, then system will match the partner that closes to this user and display on his wall.
But the problem is, i had do many research and still run out of idea of how to do it. Can anyone please help me or give me some advices?Thanks.

Below is what i trying to do but still have no idea.

[coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8tR4.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refer to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit your post accordingly and provide what you have tried so far, including your code.

Comment: post actual code and not an image of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need one sql:

```
select * from user
join 
partner on
user.user_id = partner.user_id
where
user.email = 'some@email'
```

Comment: okay noted. thanks for your help. i will try it out.